# Usar texto de gran longitud en Base de datos sqlite3

Tags: sql, c++

Estoy haciendo un programa en C++ en el que utilizo una base de datos de SQLite. Tengo atributos de tipo string que guardo como text. El problema es que cuando estos strings son de gran longitud, no los inserta ni lee como debería, si no que aparecen otros caracteres, pese a que, por lo que he leído, text soporta textos de hasta 33.000 caracteres. ¿Cuál puede ser el problema? ¿Qué puedo usar para guardar strings largos en la Base de Datos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He solucionado el problema pasándole a bind_text como último parámetro SQL_TRANSIENT en lugar de SQL_STATIC